# React app load public images in live but not in localhost

Tags: reactjs

My practice react app which is deployed at https://shakeel26.github.io/portfolio/
Works perfect but the same app doesn't load any of the image from `/public` directory in the `localhost`
I have tried multiple methods to. Import images and at the moment used one is ```
The repo is at
https://github.com/shakeel26/portfolio

Can someone answer what is wrong, one more thing to consider that images were loading 2 weeks ago and now put of nowhere they don't load in localhost.

Comment: How are you calling the local host app in the browser?

Comment: Can you check your network response preview (devtools -> network tab)

Comment: @vaibhavkanmeriya running ```npm start ``` and it opens automatically at ```localhost:3000```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the svg code instead of using the .svg filename like: image.svg

Your code:

```
backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="${encodeURIComponent(
    '#fff',
  )}" d="M9.305 1.667V3.75h1.389V1.667h-1.39zm-4.707 1.95l-.982.982L5.09 6.072l.982-.982-1.473-1.473zm10.802 0L13.927 5.09l.982.982 1.473-1.473-.982-.982zM10 5.139a4.872 4.872 0 00-4.862 4.86A4.872 4.872 0 0010 14.862 4.872 4.872 0 0014.86 10 4.872 4.872 0 0010 5.139zm0 1.389A3.462 3.462 0 0113.471 10a3.462 3.462 0 01-3.473 3.472A3.462 3.462 0 016.527 10 3.462 3.462 0 0110 6.528zM1.665 9.305v1.39h2.083v-1.39H1.666zm14.583 0v1.39h2.084v-1.39h-2.084zM5.09 13.928L3.616 15.4l.982.982 1.473-1.473-.982-.982zm9.82 0l-.982.982 1.473 1.473.982-.982-1.473-1.473zM9.305 16.25v2.083h1.389V16.25h-1.39z"/></svg>')`,
```

Try to replace URL with `../path-to-file/filename.svg`

Comment: issue isn't only .svg or any specific image. App doesn't load any image other than favicon image.

Answer (score 0):

On your component that you want to show images, import image out of style section, like this:

```
import BackGroundImage from '../../pathToImage/image.svg';
```

After, load 'BackGroundImage as component in local that you want to show:

```
<Container>
  <Header>
    <Content>
      <BackgroundImage />
    </Content>
  </Header>
</Container>
```